# Inifinite Scroll logic issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

The problem that I am facing is exactly the same as in this question - [Need small logic for infinite scroll jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101408/need-small-logic-for-infinite-scroll-jquery)

The only problem is I cannot use the accepted solution. The solution is perfect but does not work in my case.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        /*Ajax logic*/
    }
});
```

This logic asks the user to scroll to the end of the page for the condition to be satisfied and then makes the call. This used to work before but now I had to increase my footer by adding some content which is much larger than the window height. The user no longer scrolls down to the very end for this logic to work.

The solution adds an offset but the problem is that when the user scrolls up and down a little(with the solution of the above mentioned question) he makes multiple ajax calls which are not desired.

I am racking my brains but I would like to hear from you guys to!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself and jotting it down for anyone else with a similar problem.

Logically, I capped the ceiling for $(window).scrollTop() so that it doesn't increase once it reaches the footer. Subtracted the footer offset and added one more condition with the difference of 1 px. The code is like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var docHgt = $(document).height();
            var wndwHgt = $(window).height();
            var footerH = $("#footer").height();
            /* Capping to a Ceiling */
            if(scrollpos > (docHgt - wndwHgt-footerH))
                scrollpos = (docHgt - wndwHgt-footerH);
            if (( scrollpos >= (docHgt - wndwHgt-footerH))&& (scrollpos <(docHgt - wndwHgt - footerH + 1))) {
            /*Ajax logic*/
            }
});
```

Not the best way but a tradeoff!